# WO Service Address: Manually refine the XY without nulling-out the service address?

Tags: configuration, coordinates, geospatial, maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1 work orders:

I can manually enter the X & Y (LATITUDEX & LONGITUDEY) by right-clicking in the map and clicking *Set record location*.

[image]

---

However, when I do this, Maximo nulls-out the pre-existing service address. This is not what I want.

[image]

Instead, I would like to preserve the existing service address, and **further refine** its XY by defining a position on the map.

Example:

A work order is created for a pothole on a road. The WO has a service address (a property address).

A planner/scheduler would take the WO and further refine the XY (without nulling-out the service address) by placing the XY at a specific position on the road.

---

Is it possible to refine the WO's XY, without nulling-out the service address information?

<sup>*(Keyword: Maximo Spatial)*</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using maximo automation scripting.

You need to create an automation script with attribute launch points on the following fields:

- WOSERVICEADDRESS.LATITUDEY
- WOSERVICEADDRESS.LONGITUDEX
- FORMATTEDADDRESS

And use the below Jython code for the script.

```
 from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
 if (mbo.getMboValue("SADDRESSCODE").getPreviousValue() is not None):
 mbo.setValue("SADDRESSCODE",mbo.getMboValue("SADDRESSCODE").getPreviousValue().asString(),MboConstants.NOACTION)
```

Comment: Thanks. That script works well if a user manually types in a new XY (LATITUDEY or LONGITUDEX). However, it doesn't seem to work when the user uses the map to set the XY (a user would almost always use the map to enter the XY; they wouldn't manually type in an XY). The problem where the service address gets nulled-out still occurs.

Comment: I believe that the above code would work if the launch point is the save of the WOservice address since Spatial is going straight to the API and is skipping attribute validation.

Comment: This code might also work for the following scenario: *Delete the SA XY values, keep the SA text values, and use the asset’s XY as the WO pin/point.* Related: [Automatic location search order process for work orders](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSG2D3_7.6.0/com.ibm.spl.doc/plussmngr/r_auto_loc_wo_search.html).